# Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10 javascript not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I currently have a working 'dealer locator' on my test page which can be found on the right-hand side of the page

http://www.khl.com/dev/american-cranes-and-transport/

It's working fine apart from in dreaded IE, although IE11 seems to work.

When you view the page in IE you get a palceholder image which looks horrible, this occurs because the JS looks something like this:

```
<div class="storeNews">


<img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/dealer-locatot.png"   border="0">


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 

ImgPath='http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/'; 
ImgPreloadAry=new Array('placeholder.jpg','link3.png','sany3.png','manitex3.png','manitowoc3.png'); 
SRCAry=new Array(); 

for (i=0;i<ImgPreloadAry.length;i++){ 
 SRCAry[i]=new Image(); 
 SRCAry[i].src=ImgPath+ImgPreloadAry[i]; 
} 

function Cng(sel){ 
 document.getElementById('img').src=ImgPath+sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
 document.getElementById('tbl').style.backgroundImage='url('+(ImgPath+sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value)+')'; 
} 



var ImgPath='http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/';
var linksArray = [
  { Img: 'placeholder.jpg', Link : '#', RelatedText :'TEST LINK'},
  { Img: 'link3.png', Link : 'http://www.linkbelt.com/', RelatedText :'Link-belt description and link'},
  {Img:'sany3.png', Link : 'http://www.sanygroup.com/', RelatedText :'Sanny description and link'},
  {Img:'manitex3.png', Link : 'http://www.khl.com/servlet/file/Manitex%20dealer%20ad.pdf?ITEM_ENT_ID=90292&amp;COLLSPEC_ENT_ID=38&amp;ITEM_VERSION=1&amp;download=1',RelatedText : 'Manitex Locator can be downloaded below.'},
  {Img:'manitowoc3.png', Link : 'http://www.manitowoc.com/',RelatedText : 'Manitowoc description and link'},
];

function Cng(sel){ 
   var selectedIndex = sel.selectedIndex;
   document.getElementById('companyLink').href = linksArray[selectedIndex].Link;
   document.getElementById('relatedText').innerHTML= linksArray[selectedIndex].RelatedText;
   document.getElementById('relatedImage').src = ImgPath + linksArray[selectedIndex].Img;
}




//--> 
</script> 
</head>
```

Effectively ImgPath='http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/ and for some reason IE thinks that this is also an image (not a path).

Are there any bright sparks out there who can help me out?

Kind Regards,
Sam

Comment: Always a good idea to set `var` in front of variable declarations, like `var ImgPath='http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/';`

Comment: A [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20217549/1169519)? Yep, an exact duplicate...

Comment: `function Cng(sel)` is defined twice

Comment: In addition to the issues in the other comments, the last item in `linksArray` has a comma after it. Older versions of IE are very picky about that, so try removing it. Also you end the script with a `//-->` but you don't start it with the corresponding `<!--` so IE may be getting confused. Try running your code through a style checker e.g. [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Comment: @aletzo And it never seems to get called from that code, either!

Comment: ...and there's `div` and `img` elements in your `head`. They should be in the `body`. You should [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) before you question why the browsers don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

Classic trailling comma bug.

```
.....towoc description and link'},
                                ^^^
                   this comma is invalid and will break your JS in IE.
```

If you run your JS code through a validator like JSHint, you'll be warned about issues like this. And they're also very easy to spot if you use a decent IDE to edit the code, as you'll get syntax highlighting and warnings from that too.

In addition, you've declared `function Cng()` twice, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this has not helped when viewing http://www.khl.com/dev/american-cranes-and-transport/ in IE. The palceholder image still exisits before any of the selections have been made.